# How to set two different lists at the load (initial) of the page by BloC pattern in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have two List for DropDownList in my form, I use BloC pattern, I yield 4 State for one Event in demand_**bloc.dart** page.

```
  @override
  Stream<DemandAddState> mapEventToState(DemandAddEvent event) async* {
    if (event is InitListLoadEvent) {
      yield* _setInitListToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<DemandAddState> _setInitListToState(InitListLoadEvent event) async* {
    yield InitListLoading();
    try {

      List data = await demandAddRepository.getEmployeeList();
      yield EmployeeListLoaded(data: data);

      List data2 = await demandAddRepository.getDayOffList();
      yield DayOffListLoaded(data2: data2);

    } catch (_) {
      yield InitListError();
    }
  }
```

my demand_**state.dart** is

```
class InitListLoading extends DemandAddState {}

class InitListError extends DemandAddState {}

class EmployeeListLoaded extends DemandAddState {
  final List data;

  const EmployeeListLoaded({@required this.data}) : assert(data != null);

}

class DayOffListLoaded extends DemandAddState {
  final List data2;

  const DayOffListLoaded({@required this.data2}) : assert(data2 != null);

}
```

after, and on my demand_**page.dart**,

I need to give **data**, **data2**,

but unfortunately, data is became Null.

```
    body: BlocProvider<DemandAddBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return DemandAddBloc(demandAddRepository: demandAddRepository)
          ..add(InitListLoadEvent());
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<DemandAddBloc, DemandAddState>(
        builder: (context, demandAddState) {
          if (demandAddState is InitListLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          if (demandAddState is DayOffListLoaded) {
            data2 = demandAddState.data2;
          }
          if (demandAddState is EmployeeListLoaded) {
            data = demandAddState.data;
          }

          if (demandAddState is InitListError){ ... }


          return ...
          ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(

                    children: [

                       _buildDropDownFormField(data),

                       _buildDropDownFormField(data2),

                        ....
```

I lost **data** after the end process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because BLoC only has 1 state at a time. What you can do is either make a separate BLoC  to handle both state or make a new state class.

```
class ListLoaded extends DemandAddState {
   final List<Employee> data;
   final List<DayOff> data2;
}
```

```
    body: BlocProvider<DemandAddBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        return DemandAddBloc(demandAddRepository: demandAddRepository)
          ..add(InitListLoadEvent());
      },
      child: BlocBuilder<DemandAddBloc, DemandAddState>(
        builder: (context, demandAddState) {
          if (demandAddState is InitListLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          }
          if (demandAddState is ListLoaded) {
            data = demandAddState.data;
            data2 = demandAddState.data2;

            return ...
            ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                         _buildDropDownFormField(data),
                         _buildDropDownFormField(data2),
                       ....
          }
          if (demandAddState is InitListError){
            return ..
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my **_state.dart**

```
class InitListLoading extends DemandAddState {}

class InitListError extends DemandAddState {}

class InitListLoaded extends DemandAddState {
  final List data;
  final List data2;

  const InitListLoaded({@required this.data,  @required this.data2}) : assert(data != null, data2 != null);
}
```

and my **_page.dart**

```
          ...
          if (demandAddState is InitListLoaded) {
            dataDayOffList = demandAddState.data2;
            dataEmployeeList = demandAddState.data;
          }
          ...
```